# Test AJAX file upload

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I want to test the file upload in my application. The upload itself is handled as described in  section **Direct file upload** on http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaFileUpload.

I am using the latest Play20 version and build it as described [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/BuildingFromSource).

My current code looks like this, but obviously the part is missing which adds a test file to the request:

**Test.java**

```java
FakeRequest request = fakeRequest(POST, "/measurement/123/file");
// how to append test file to this request?    
Result result = routeAndCall(request);
assertOK(result);
```

**Controller.java**

```java
public static uploadFile() {
    RequestBody body = request().body();
    if (body != null) {
        RawBuffer rawBuffer = body.asRaw();
        if (rawBuffer != null) {
            File uploadedFile = rawBuffer.asFile();
            // ...
        }
    }
    return ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Play 2 Java file upload testing has been to create a UploadFakeRequest extending FakeRequest. Inside the class I have then my own withRawBody method with something like that:

```
 RawBuffer raw = new RawBuffer(1000, data.getBytes()); // No clue what is the correct value here...
 AnyContentAsRaw content = new AnyContentAsRaw(raw);
 fake = new play.api.test.FakeRequest(POST, fake.path(), new play.api.test.FakeHeaders(Scala.asScala(map)), content, "127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the FakeRequest call, as per [source code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Fakes.scala#L35), is:

```
case class FakeRequest[A](method: String, uri: String, headers: FakeHeaders, body: A) extends Request[A]
```

You should be able to inspect the body of a POST request that uploads a file to your application and copy that body as a parameter in your testing code. The alternative is to build it as per [RFC description](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) on multipart POST.

Comment: Can you give an example how to do that?